# String Function issues

Tags: python, string, function

Attempting to create a bibliography format function

```
def bibformat_mla(author,title,city,publisher,year):

    return "author. title. city: publisher, year"
    author = ('Perry')
    title = ('Personal Identity')
    city = ('London')
    publisher = ('University of California Press')
    year = (2008)
    print (author + title + city + publisher + year)
```

My code doesn't seem to work. Help?

Comment: What Language is that. Basic?

Comment: I'm assuming this is python. Shouldn't your return be at the end of your function? It never gets past that point when it's at the beginning.

Comment: I'm running python 2.7

Comment: I'm attempting to return an output in the format

"author. title. city: publisher, year"

Comment: Note that you're immediately overwriting all arguments (`author`, `title`...) in your function.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully, this will get you heading in the right direction:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


def bibformat_mla(author, title, city, publisher, year):
    return '%s. %s. %s: %s, %s' % (author, title, city, publisher, year)


def main():
    author = 'Perry'
    title = 'Personal Identity'
    city = 'London'
    publisher = 'University of California Press'
    year = 2008

    s = bibformat_mla(author, title, city, publisher, year)
    print s


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I always prefer to use the new string formatting method (`.format()`) as it can be more clear and is advised by the Python Docs

Comment: Good call, Nick T. I really should start using it... I'm still using Python 2.6, and I'm kind of attached to the C-style formatting method.

Comment: It's in Python 2.6, but you can't be super lazy and just say `{}, {}...`, you'd need to say `{0}, {1}...`. I think you can use text (rather than numeric) labels for the fields and pump in a dictionary in 2.6 though.

Comment: Yeah, I was playing with it a couple of days ago. It doesn't seem to work with keyword args or a dict, though.

Comment: But I _can_ do this: `print "%(a)s %(b)s %(c)s" % {'c':3,'a':1,'b':2}` which prints `1 2 3`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a major problem here. Your `return` is at the beginning of your function. As the `return` statement breaks out of the function, your code will never get past the `return`.

You have two possible solutions.

1. Change `return` to `print`?
   Instead of `return` you possibly meant to `print` it out:

---

```
def bibformat_mla(author,title,city,publisher,year):

    print "author. title. city: publisher, year"
    author = ('Perry')
    title = ('Personal Identity')
    city = ('London')
    publisher = ('University of California Press')
    year = (2008)
    print (author + title + city + publisher + year)
```

---

2. Move `return`?
   Instead of keeping the `return` at the top of the function, you could move it to the bottom:

---

```
def bibformat_mla(author,title,city,publisher,year):

    author = ('Perry')
    title = ('Personal Identity')
    city = ('London')
    publisher = ('University of California Press')
    year = (2008)
    print (author + title + city + publisher + year)
    return "author. title. city: publisher, year"
```

Comment: how do you post code? doesn't work.
does anybody get what i'm trying to do?

Comment: @DaveKeddy : You can post more code by editing your question and pasting the new code at the end, preferably with some kind of explanation.

Comment: You might want to consider the issue that the OP is overriding all arguments. You do the same, thus making all arguments unnecessary.